# Groupby by name and get a dataframe with hierarical columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to refresh my panda-skills but I cannot recollect this operation

How to turn a `Dataframe` similar to this (first column is the index):

```
           token    open   close
2013-01-02  AAPL  553.82  549.03
2013-01-02  GOOG  719.42  723.25
2013-01-03  AAPL  547.88  542.10
2013-01-03  GOOG  724.93  723.67
```

into a `Dataframe` with this structure:

```
              AAPL            GOOG
              open   close    open   close
2013-01-02  553.82  549.03  719.42  723.25
2013-01-03  547.88  542.10  724.93  723.67
```

That is grouping by `token` and get a new `Dataframe` with the first level of the column labels being the groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.pivot_table(df, values=['open', 'close'], rows=df.index, cols='token')
```

gives you:

```
              open           close
              AAPL    GOOG    AAPL    GOOG
2013-01-02  553.82  719.42  549.03  723.25
2013-01-03  547.88  724.93  542.10  723.67
```

That is, the hierarchical columns names are in reverse order of what you wanted, but I think that's the logic (top column name is describing the values).